# for all $a>0$ find supremum of $f(x)=a^{-x} + a^{\frac{-1}{x}} \in (0;+\infty)$

Tags: calculus, analysis

As in topic, this quest is marked as a rather difficult. All I suppose is that it has something to do with maybe defining a helpful function like $$g(x):= \ln {f(x)}$$ and then doing something with $g'(x)$, but I am not quite sure why do I have to act that way. Could anyone give a hint? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** First note that if $a = 1$ then $f(x)$ is constant.  So let's assume $a \neq 1$.

1. If $a < 1$ then what is the limit of $a^{-x}$ as $x \to \infty$?
2. If $a > 1$ then what is the limit of $a^\frac{-1}{x}$ as $x \to \infty$?